# visual studioでのサーバー接続ができない。

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server

Visual studio2017を使い、SQL Serverとの接続の確認をするため簡単なWebFormApplicationでプログラミングを書いて確認しようとしたのですが、テスト接続とビルドは正常にいったのですが、実際に動かすと「ハンドルされていない例外」とでてきます。何が原因でしょうか。

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestConnection2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string conString = "Server = localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            con.Open();
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                string q="insert into User (id,name) values ('"+textID.Text.ToString()+"','"+textName.Text.ToString()+"')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q,con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection made Successfuly.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: テスト接続とは具体的にはどうやって確認しました？
プロジェクトはWebFormで間違いないですか？
その場合はWindows認証はお勧めできません。SQL Server認証で明示的にユーザー名とパスワードを指定すれば接続できませんか？

Answer (score -1):

同じコードを使って、問題ありませんでした。SQLEXPRESSの問題でしょうか。Userのテーブルはmasterのデータベースにあれば原因わかりません。